# Change Accordion of Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I am working on a design in which I need `accordian` as per the attached image, I have tried using jquery . Currently the look is at the link :

http://themekart.com/demo/spasalon/shortcode.html

We want to change the color of the text and +/- on open or close of the accordion ?

How we can do this please help us

Thanks...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want some js to create all of this for you,

check DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/BhBHf/5/

## JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accordion .accordion-toggle').each(function(){
        $(this).html('<span class="plus">+</span>'+$(this).text());
    });
    $('.accordion a').on('click',function(){
        var cur = $(this).children('.plus').text();
        // set all to default state
        $('.accordion a').children('.plus').text('+');
        $('.accordion a').css({'color':'#666'});
        // then, change style of current one        
        if(cur=='+'){
            $(this).children('.plus').text('-');
            $(this).css({'color':'red'});
        }
        else{
            $(this).children('.plus').text('+');
            $(this).css({'color':'#666'});
        }
    });
});
```

## CSS

```
.plus {
    float:left;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    background:#fff;
    margin:0 5px 0 0;
    color:#666;
}
```

Comment: Yep thats working but a doubt is there that if I am clicking on 2nd accordion then the text of the 1st accordion header not changed

Answer (score 2):

This is all css business.
You can make the `.accordion-toggle` red and `.accordion-toggle.collapsed` gray. As for the image you can either put an `<img>` tag in front of the link or give it margin and use css to put the plus/minus in. (using same criteria as above.)

Css:

```
.accordion-toggle{
    color:red;
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed {
    color:gray;
}
```

And for the icon you can use the twitter bootstrap icons.

```
<i class="icon-minus"></i>
<i class="icon-plus"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the color of the text using the class .accordion-toggle, line 6082 from bootstrap.css. I don't suggest you to edit the bootstrap file. Instead of that, you could include your css (my-own-style.css) after Bootstrap's (bootstrap.css) so you could override rules by redefining them.

If you are using SASS, you could change the variables before you import bootstrap. Read this:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables

About the +/- buttons, you could use something like this to toggle the button class:
http://pastebin.com/y4RxdEgH

Where your button classes would be icon-chevron-up and icon-chevron-down.